# angular2/Django rest application browser asks for login after application login

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I am building an app with angular2 on frontend and Django rest on backend. Even after I login to my application, browser asks for login once again like following:

[image]

This happens each day, but not on consecutive logins in the same day. Why does this happen?

My Django rest configuration code:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
       'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
       'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
```

and angular2 service:

```
  login(username: string, password: string) {

    let body = JSON.stringify({
      'username' : username, 
      'password': password
    });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this._authenticationUrl + 'login/', body, options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError)
  }
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: if you're accessing your API only from angular in a browser, it may help to remove `TokenAuthentication` and `BasicAuthentication`.

Comment: My angular code and Django code are completely separate they both run on different ports. My API returns token which I store in local storage

Answer (score 0):

I had following in my code which was causing problem:

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove

```
'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
```

from `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`, and keep

```
'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
```

in `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`.